# .htaccess - Multiple domains to the same root folder - multiple languages

Tags: .htaccess, multilingual, multiple-domains

I have multiple domains pointed to the same root folder.

the website are multilingual. Language is setup by a session variable

I have **www.domain.com/index.php?lang=en (default)**

**www.domain.com/index.php?lang=da (danish)**

also I have www.domain.dk

How cam I point **www.domain.dk** to **www.domain.dk/index.php?land=da**

The URL I want to remain as it is :

1. if .com -> url: -> http:www.domain.com
2. if .dk -> url: -> http:www.domain.dk

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this .htaccess code might help

> RewriteEngine on RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m. RewriteRule ^$
>   {HTTP_HOST}/index.php?land=da [R,L]

This will affect all your domain as all your domain is using the same index.php.
In your index.php check which host you are browsing.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='domain.dk') {
    header("Location: www.domain.dk/index.php?land=da"); // Redirect browser

    //if there are scripts below this code insert this
    exit; // Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect
}
```

Comment: but index.php on www.domain.dk is the same index.php for www.domain.com.

Comment: Ive edited my answer. but in your second comment you said it does not have to affect domain.com. so i will edit my answer again. sorry.

Comment: Thank you. Seams proper condition. I'll try it and let you know. Thank you